# почему в функции makeMove в консоли пустой массив?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

я новичек в реакт, никак не могу понять почему когда я нажимаю на шашку, а потом на пустое поле у меня в функции makeMove в консоли пустой массив ?

```
 import React, { useState } from 'react';
import classes from './Board.module.css';


function Board() {
    let [possibleMoves, setPossibleMoves] = useState([]);
    let [currentСell, setCurrentCell] = useState(0);
    let [board, setBoard] = useState([...Array(64)].map((_, ind) => {
        const row = Math.floor(ind / 8);
        const col = ind % 8;
        const isBlack = (row + col) % 2 === 1;
        const cellColor = isBlack ? classes.blackCell : classes.whiteCell;
        if (ind > 39 && isBlack) {
            return <div key={ind}className={cellColor}>
                <div onClick={() => getPossibleMoves(ind)} className={classes.greenChecker} ></div>
            </div>
        } else if (ind < 24 && isBlack) {
            return <div key={ind} className={cellColor}>
                <div onClick={() => getPossibleMoves(ind)} className={classes.pinkChecker} ></div>
            </div>
        }
        return <div key={ind} onClick={(e) => makeMove(e,ind)} className={cellColor}>{ind}</div>
    }))


    function getPossibleMoves(ind) {
        setPossibleMoves([ind + 7, ind + 9, ind - 7, ind - 9].filter(el => {
            if (el > 0 && el < 63 && board[el].props.className.includes('black')) return el;
            else return false;
        }))
    }

    function makeMove(e,ind) {
        setCurrentCell(prevInd => ind);
        console.log(possibleMoves)
    }


    return (
        <div className={classes.board}>
            {board}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Board;
```

Answer (score 0):

useState берет значение из инициализатора только в момент первого вызова, и там соответственно функция захвачена на момент первого вызова, поэтому данные в ней как были в начале и не обновляются. Функции, как и все переменные, тоже пересоздаются каждый раз в момент вызова компонента.
В вашем случае useState вообще не нужен. Просто сразу переменной board присваивайте то что в инициализаторе стейта.